# Add multiline content to button in c# windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, button, text, windows-phone, multiline

I have an app with some button which contains different text, of different length. When the text is longer than the width of the button, only the first part of the text is displayed.
Is there a way to dynamically split the text in 2 lines or more?
Thanks

Comment: You'll have to increase the height of the button and the text will go to the next line if it can accomodate the size of the font. Try that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `TextBlock` to define  button content and set `TextWrapping` property.

```
<Button>
  <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">your text</TextBlock>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

For specific breaks in your text I like to use Runs and LineBreaks

```
<Button>
  <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="9">
    <Run Text="Bind some text here" />
    <LineBreak/>
    <Run Text="Add some more text" />
  </TextBlock>
</Button>
```

Comment: I agree, it is a good idea, but when the text is changed, you need to choose where it should be slipped, and that's more complicated :)